# freeze header row for table asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I want the header row to not move when I scroll down the table. I tried adding `position:fixed` in the Style of `TableHeaderRow` but that messes up the formatting of the title.
This is the code I have in the `.aspx` file.

```
<asp:Table ID="tblName" runat="server" class="tblName" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow ForeColor="White" BackColor="DodgerBlue" Style="position:fixed ;background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #6688FF, #AACCFF);  height: 4em; text-align: center; text-transform: capitalize;">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Action" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="title" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="title2" /> 
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="title3" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="title4" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="title5" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="title6" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="title7" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="title8" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="title9" />
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Comment" />
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Comment: why you want to use asp tableheader row? cant you use simple table and div?

Comment: I can but this is code that was given to me. I was told to implement the feature with the table already written like this. If I were to rewrite the code from scratch I would definitely use a simple table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use normal html table then you use this code

```
<table style="width: 300px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
   <td>Column 1</td>
   <td>Column 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div style="overflow: auto;height: 100px; width: 320px;">
 <table style="width: 300px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Value 1</td>
   <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Value 1</td>
   <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Value 1</td>
  <td>Value 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```